# Problemas al desplegar una aplicacion web

Tags: java, hibernate, primefaces, glassfish

Hola qué tal muy buenas tardes, espero y se encuentren bien! Tengo el siguiente problema:

No puedo desplegar la aplicación y me genera un mensaje error; por este medio les hare llegar un Screenshot del error que me aparece y aquí por igual el mensaje:

```
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Cyberkof\Documents\NetBeansProjects\sysFacturacion\build\web
GlassFish Server, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\Cyberkof\Documents\NetBeansProjects\sysFacturacion\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1054: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 10 seconds)
```

Este es el codigo que me arroja en la pestaña de GlassFish Server:

```
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
Información:   visiting unvisited references
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Grave:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-000072: Bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable.  Bean:  Managed Bean [class sys.bean.clienteBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-000072: Bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable.  Bean:  Managed Bean [class sys.bean.clienteBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.checkType(ManagedBean.java:203)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(AbstractBean.java:105)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(ManagedBean.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.doAfterBeanDiscovery(BeanDeployer.java:343)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.afterBeanDiscovery(BeanDeployment.java:277)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:408)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:222)
    ... 41 more

Grave:   Exception while loading the app
Grave:   Undeployment failed for context /sysFacturacion
Grave:   Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-000072: Bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable.  Bean:  Managed Bean [class sys.bean.clienteBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-000072: Bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable.  Bean:  Managed Bean [class sys.bean.clienteBean] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.checkType(ManagedBean.java:203)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(AbstractBean.java:105)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(ManagedBean.java:113)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.doAfterBeanDiscovery(BeanDeployer.java:343)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.afterBeanDiscovery(BeanDeployment.java:277)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:408)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
introducir el código aquí
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, cualquier detalle que haga falta con gusto lo reviso, de antemano les mando un cordial saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota:Estoy usado glassfish 4.1

Clase clienteBean:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sys.bean;

import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import sys.dao.clienteDao;
import sys.imp.clienteDaoImp;
import sys.model.Cliente;

/**
 *
 * @author Cyberkof
 */
@Named(value = "clienteBean")
@ViewScoped
public class clienteBean {

      //Se definen dos variables
    private List<Cliente> listaClientes;
    private Cliente cliente;

    public clienteBean() {
        cliente = new Cliente();
    }

    //Aqui se definen los metodos getters y setters
    public void setListaClientes(List<Cliente> listaClientes) {
        this.listaClientes = listaClientes;
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    //en donde se van a llena es con el metodo "getListaClientes"
    public List<Cliente> getListaClientes() {
        clienteDao cDao = new clienteDaoImp();
        listaClientes = cDao.listarCliente();
        return listaClientes;
    }

    //Este metodo sera para que cargue el formulario insertar cliente es decir cargue vacio
    public void prepararNuevoCliente(){
    cliente= new Cliente(); 
    }

    public void nuevoCliente(){
    clienteDao cDao = new clienteDaoImp();
    cDao.newCliente(cliente);
    }

    public void modificarCliente(){
    clienteDao cDao = new clienteDaoImp();
    cDao.updateCliente(cliente);
    cliente = new Cliente();
    }

    public void eliminaCliente(){
    clienteDao cDao = new clienteDaoImp();
    cDao.deleteCliente(cliente);
    cliente = new Cliente();
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor pega el código que sale en la pestaña "Glassfish server" ya que ésta es la que tiene el `stacktrace` que se necesita para saber qué está fallando.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder me, ya hice lo que me pediste y volvi a editar mi pregunta, cualquier detalle lo reviso  saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error:

> org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment
>   failure:WELD-000072: Bean declaring a passivating scope must be
>   passivation capable.  Bean:  Managed Bean [class sys.bean.clienteBean]

Significa que hay un managed bean que **no** implementa `Serializable`.

[CDI](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#_built_in_scopes) requiere que `@SessionScoped, @ConversationScoped, @FlowScoped, @ViewScoped` sean `Serializable`.

### Solución

Según el error, `[sys.bean.clienteBean]`

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named(value = "clienteBean")
@ViewScoped
public class clienteBean implements Serializable{
// el resto del código
}
```

Comment: Ese fragmento en que parte del codigo lo pondria? mira, voy a volver a editar la pregunta, y en esa edicion pondre la clase de "clienteBean"

Comment: @cratus666jose revisa la respuesta, ahí está arreglado según tu error.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, ya quedo muchisimas gracias volvi a editar el comentario por que me habia faltado meter en una clase pero ya se pudo deployar ahora solo queda ver unos detalles pero eso lo solucionare de verdad muchisimas gracias

Comment: @cratus666jose Vale, si te funcionó la respuesta por favor marcarla como correcta.